# Responsive two iframe videos side by side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make two iframe videos side by side (for PC users) and a one above the other one (for phone users).
I have tried this , and it works for the phone but for the PC they still above each other not side by side which I need .
**For Css:**

```css
<style> 
.embed-containerr {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.embed-containerr iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

</style>
```

**For html :**

```html
<center><div class="containerr-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="embed-containerr">
                  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xbzX99Iy7xg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="embed-containerr">
                  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BfmfZw_NIYg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div></center>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added the code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this , and solved my problem

```html
<div class="vimeo-wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="vimeo-video-1 vimeo-standard">
                              <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xbzX99Iy7xg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div>
        <div class="vimeo-video-2 vimeo-standard">
                              <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BfmfZw_NIYg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
 .vimeo-wrapper {
        max-width: 980px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .vimeo-standard {
        float: left;
        height: 300px;
        width: 47%;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }


    @media (max-width:767px) {

        .vimeo-standard {
            float: none;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
    }

    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: " "; /* 1 */
        display: table; /* 2 */
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ahj6h/

Answer (score 0):

If you put this between them, I think that it should do what you want. There is probably a more simple way to do it though.

```
<div class="mobileShow">
<br>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  .mobileShow {display: none;}

  /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
  @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 320px)
    and (max-device-width : 480px){ 
      .mobileShow {display: inline;}
  }
</style>
```